# How to use immer to value to nested fields which have optional parents, in typescript?

Tags: typescript, immer.js

When I have an object which has nested optional fields, like:

```
type FormState = {
  aaa?: {
    bbb?: {
      ccc?: number
    }
  }
}
```

When I want to set value to `aaa.bbb.ccc` in typescript, I have to:

```
import produce from "immer";

const formState: FormState = {}

const target = produce(formState, draft => {
  draft.aaa = draft.aaa ?? {}
  draft.aaa.bbb = draft.aaa.bbb ?? {}
  draft.aaa.bbb.ccc = 1;
})
```

Is there any way to make it simpler?

The optional chaining syntax isn't work here:

```
draft?.aaa?.bbb?.ccc = 1;  // compilation error
```

A small demo: https://github.com/freewind-demos/typescript-immer-set-value-to-nested-optional-fields-demo

Comment: You can make it shorter, but I would argue not simpler [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9gJwLYGVgENjQLxQN4BQUU6pA-AFz5HFQBGDl1ttAxu0wHYCuSdECGsQC+NUaIKs4nAM7AoAM0SoMWKvGRpMOfMIDcBSdLlQMCAOYR5uMAjgATbqwgAKJZtUQANFBd4SpFT+DHRBUOysULgAjFDCUbpxCXjxwgCUUQB8zFAIVtwInPgB6GEhYRFJqQbpRrJwADYQAHQNcOYuZpbAaQZS9U2t7Z3oFlbNpOjNIc0RvYYECtycrMAAltJQtg5Oru4q2urKWlg+22DcDYe+9gjoCsBHHtoZ2NkAIhAQYABKEACO3DWeXsAB4NAcsJkMoRiHlgAUiudLto3MdPPMJKBIFBPt8-oDgRAwQAVbK4fwAbQAClA1kUANYQEBwBRQEkAXQAtEw8b8AUCQaCSTSOdlhEA) it does validate that you initialize everything declared.

Comment: This is better I think [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9gJwLYGVgENjQLxQN4BQUU6pA-AFz5HFQBGDl1ttAxu0wHYCuSdECGsQC+NUaIKs4nAM7AoAM0SoMWKvGRpMOfMIDcBSdLlQMCAOYR5uMAjgATbqwgAKJZtUQANFHsJ0CtYAfMxQCFbcCJz4JKRUeFAAdMl+AcCJpOg+DHTxUOysVACMPsmJqYEZ5Ik5UMJ1DWRkugbCAJRGsnAANhCJ3XDmLmaWwG0GUl29-YPD6BZWVeg1DIkF44YECtycrMAAltJQtg5Oru4q2urKWlg+J2Dc3VdQLhXA1x7abVDYIQAiEAgYAAShAAI7cfbhewAHg0lywQR+hGI4WAkWiDye2jcN08GwkoEgUEBwLBkOhEDhABUQrgEgBtAAKUH20QA1hAQHAFFAaQBdAC0TDJoIhUJhsJpLIFIWEQA)